# awk: Columns are not printed when concatenating strings is passed as command string

Tags: sed, awk

I've found some anomaly when writing a script.

The following examples works as expected:

```
$ echo 123 | awk '{print $1 456}'
123456
$ sh -c "echo 123 | awk '{print $1}'"
123
```

But the following example, doesn't:

```
$ sh -c "echo 123 | awk '{print $1 456}'"
456
```

I'm expecting to print the 1st column with the additional string, which should return `123456` as it does when running the same command without`sh -c`. But what is happening, the 1st column is ignored for some reason. What's interesting, `$1` is printed without problems when not performing string concatenation.

Why this is happening and how to do string concatenation within the command which is passed to separate instance of shell?

Comment: I think it may help you to understand what’s going on in this situation if you realize that your second example, `sh -c "echo 123 | awk '{print $1}'"`, is “working for the wrong reason” – it’s not doing what you think it’s doing. Try `sh -c "echo 123 456 | awk '{print $1}'"` – it will print `123 456`, because the `$1` gets replaced by the current value of `$1` *in the shell* (which is nothing) early in the interpretation of the command, so `awk` gets the command string `{print }`, causing it to print every line in its entirety, not just the first column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must escape `$` sign:

```
$ sh -c "echo 123 | awk '{print \$1 456}'"
123456
```

Otherwise, `$1` is expanded by current shell.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Why I don't have to to escape it, when not doing string concatenation?

Comment: @kenorb: because in this case, `awk` statement only have `'{print}'`, which by default print $0.